# How can I import a list of contacts from MailChimp to the database all at once?

Tags: import

I am looking to import a list of 185 contacts from MailChimp to our database and wanted to know how I can do this in one go. As far as I know I have to export the list from Mail Chimp and then edit the fields in an excel document, but how to I make sure the fields will match with those in CiviCRM?  Does anyone have or know where there is a template of what needs to be on the spreadsheet?
Are there any guides to how to layout the columns to refer to the fields I want to mark in Civi, also can I stop it importing duplicate contacts?
Thank you!
Grace

Answer (score 1):

There is a mailchimp extension which you could install in CiviCRM and which then connects to your mailchimp and imports the contacts from mailchimp into CiviCRM.

Comment: Thank you! I don't have much of an idea of how to install an extension. Is it quite easy to do and not a big job, or would it be something I should ask our technician for support with?

Comment: Installing an extension is not that diificult. Some extensions could be installed from within CiviCRM it self. Others you have to upload to the right folder and could then be installed. 
See the documentation on how to do so: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/extensions/
If that sounds too techie I would recommand ask your technician.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are doing a one off transfer of what is a relatively small set of contacts then an export from MailChimp and then import to CiviCRM is easiest option. Depends on what fields you have in MailChimp (is it more than name and email?) I'd just export everything from MailChimp and then you can set which fields you want to import and where to map them in the CiviCRM contact import. If you need to do any adjustment, then I find Excel the easiest place to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MAILCHIMP CIVICRM INTEGRATION](https://civicrm.org/extensions/mailchimp-civicrm-integration) extension to import contacts to civicrm based on mailchimp as wells as to mailchimp based on civicrm.

Answer (score 0):

To just answer the simple version of the question - you can use the Import Wizard at Contacts > Import Contacts which is also at this path civicrm/import/contact?reset=1